# My program, which I designed for multi-platform, is OK on Android, but problematic on Windows. Error : Invalid Parameter

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

```
// ConnectionRemote   :TSQLConnection; 
// CDSBilgiler        :TClientDataSet; 
// CDSBilgilerID      :TIntegerField;    // Not arAutoInc
// CDSBilgilerVALUE   :TWideStringField;
// CDSBilgilerPC      :TSmallintField;
// DSProvConnBilgiler :TDSProviderConnection;
// DSProvConnBilgiler.ServerClassName := TServerMethods1
// DSProvConnBilgiler.Connection      := ConnectionRemote

   CDSBilgiler.Edit;             
   CDSBilgilerPC.AsInteger := 1;
   CDSBilgiler.Post;
   Showmessage('Point - 1');
   CDSBilgiler.ApplyUpdates(-1);       // The problematic line is here. Error : Invalid Parameter.
   Showmessage('Point - 2');           // 2nd message not displayed after error  
   CDSBilgiler.Close;
```

I've looked at all the threads about ApplyUpdates() on your site.
I've been trying for almost a week, but I couldn't find the solution.
Thank you in advance to those who help.

Comment: Where is your TDataSetProvider?

Comment: I missed it because I added the codes here manually. Thanks for your warning. I applied the fix.

Comment: Where is your TADOQuery? Does it have 1 or more parameters?

Comment: Mr. Freddie Bell. I don't see why AdoQuery would be needed in this case. My project is running stable in Android environment. It gives an error in Windows environment with the same codes.Also, thank you for continuing to follow the thread.

Comment: Where are the updates applied to? What is the underlying data storage here? Where is it loaded from? Why not just use `LogChanges := False` after the CDS is opened, or `MergeChangeLog` after each post?

Comment: CDSBilgilerPC.AsInteger := 1; 
This is a PC controlled flag. It notifies that data has come to the table or tables for itself. I can't understand your questions. There is a simplified code block in the topic I opened.
- Question : Why can't I apply updates to a field in the database on the server?
As I said before, this code is;
The client is causing a problem on the PC.
The client does not cause problems on Android.